# Sorting by highest value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code that sorts out the names alphabetically and it also prints the maximum value of the score achieved by the name. However, I'm very baffled to how I can get it to output the names with the highest maximum score down to the lowest maximum score.

```
info = open("resultsA.txt", "r")
splitting =[line.split(",") for line in info]
sorting = sorted(splitting, key=lambda v:v[0])
results= [(name, max(a+b+c)) for name, a, b, c in sorting]
for name, score in results:
    print(name+"-"+score)
    info.close()
```

The code above sorts the data stored in resultsA.txt by alphabetical order and the maximum value however I need it to sort out the data from the highest maximum value to the lowest maximum value.

[image: What the code outputs]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` you are sorting on is `v[0]` and, from the rest of your code it looks like `v[0]` is the name. Changing the key to sort on the max score will fix the issue.

So first you have to compute:

`results = [(name, max(a+b+c)) for name, a, b, c in splitting]`.

Then sort on the second element of each tuple:

`results = sorted(results, key = lambda v: v[1])`

*However* `sorted` will give you the results in lowest to highest order by default (which makes sense because we usually count up). So in your case you also have to tell it to reverse the ordering:

`results = sorted(results, key = lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: Thank you very much! You have helped me out amazingly!